# Creating a heatmap with 2 different grades of colour in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following data setup for creating a heatmap in R:

```
dat = data.frame(A=c(2,3,0,1), B=c(1,4, 1,0), C=c(4,0,1,1), D=c(2,0,0,4))
rownames(dat) <- c("SKy", "Ing", "Lowl", "embow")
dat.mat = as.matrix(dat)
heatmap(dat.mat, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA)
```

Output:

[image]

As shown in the heatmap output, there is a grading of coulor from light cream to wine/burgundy colour to highlight values 0 to 6. I need help to have gradual shades of red to cover values 0 to 6 in columns A and B, and gradual shades of green to cover values 0 to 6 in columns C and D.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure whether this helps but it might at least point you in some direction.
You could define two color schemes, one for cols `A` and `B`, one for `C` and `D`, e.g.:

```
myCol_AB <- c("orange", "orangered", "red", "firebrick")
myCol_CD <- c("aquamarine", "chartreuse", "green", "green4")
```

In the call to `heatmap` you could insert an `ifelse` statement assigning `myCol_AB` to cols `A`and `B` and `myCol_CD` to `C`and `D`:

```
heatmap(dat.mat, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, 
        col = ifelse(dat.mat[, 1:2], myCol_AB, myCol_CD))
```